# How to remove the bottomTabs button press effect on Android react-native-navigation (Wix)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation v2 from wix (3.7.0) Is there a way to remove the ugly icon mini-zoom and bubble effect it does when any bottomTabs button is pressed? This only happens on Android, iOS doesn't do that. I'm guessing is the normal default Android behaviour, but is there a way to completely remove it?

I couldn't find any variable within Navigation.setDefaultOptions or bottomTabs that allowed me that, the only thing it does seem there is, is the animation for push or pop and such.

Answer (score 1):

modifying the setRoot animations is now supported. You can set it in default options before calling setRoot or declare the desired animations in the root options.
Note that this is implemented only on Android.

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  animations: {
    setRoot: {
      alpha: {
        from: 0,
        to: 1,
        duration: 500
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I see, so if I want to avoid that animation and increasing its size i have to set duration to 0?

Comment: There's also a scaleX and scaleY, i will try to set them to 1.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. Keeps showing the same default bottom tab button animations when they are being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think `bottomTabs.titleDisplayMode: 'alwaysShow'` is what you're looking for. if you don't want to show the tab's title then use `alwaysHide` instead.

Comment: hey guy, no.. i dont want to hide the titles, i dont want anything to jump in size, i dont want them to move (animations), i'd like them to behave exactly as in iOS. Everything remains static there, only the activeIcon changes when tapped.

Comment: That's currently not possible. The closes you can get to disabling the animation is by using `titleDisplayMode: 'alwaysShow'` - I'll try to add an option to remove the animation asap

Comment: thanks man, really appreciate it. And if u can also add an option to remove the bubble fadeOut effect behind the button when tapped, would be awesome too! :) im looking forward to your change.

Answer (score 0):

**`'alwaysShow'`** is the **default**.

You can override it by this:

```
titleDisplayMode: 'alwaysHide'
```